# "No tests found" in vscode "Testing" tab for c++ google test

Tags: visual-studio-code, g++, googletest, vscode-debugger

VSCode version: `1.67.2`
My google test application is built and run successfully from VSCode by selecting the target and I can see the test output in the terminal, set breakpoint and such. However, there is no tests shown in the "Testing" tab in VSCode. What do I miss? Any advice and insight is appreciated.